# No single MVC framework for PHP with complete features like persistence api, ORM, annotations and dependency injection

Tags: java, php, spring-mvc, playframework-2.0

Hello friends I was searching from last few days for a good PHP MVC framework which has features like [Spring Web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/mvc.html) or [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) for Java(ORM, Annotations and dependency injection etc.). Let me clear I am not going to compare two programming languages java and PHP, I just want to know somewhere any single PHP framework exists with above all functionalities. I know PHP has good frameworks  like codeigniter, zend and cakePHP but when I searched the above features in PHP then I get different links. When I googled the features individually for php then I got below results

[mosquito-php5-persistence-api](https://code.google.com/p/mosquito-php5-persistence-api/wiki/UsersGuide), 
[Dependency Injection Container for PHP 5.3](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), [Propel is an open-source Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) for SQL-Databases in PHP 5.4](http://propelorm.org/)

I am not demanding anything I just want some useful links or suggestion from your side because I want to use PHP for business projects, so before started I want some more detail about it.

Thanks in advance, please share your experience.

Comment: Oh, but I put my effort in my post and I just want user's opinions and their experiences in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read aboout each framework, not individaul features. Sometimes frameworks provide different ORM's or features, you can even use it without any ORM for example.

I believe that at least [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/) and [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) have all of mentioned functionality and much more.

As for myself I use "more-lightweight" [Yii framework](http://yiiframework.com), it has good ORM through CActiveRecord and it have many extensions and github repos with thousands of features.

After quick googling I found several Dependency Injection Container extensions like that [DI container](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40694-yii-dependency-injection-container-tutorial/) and [annotation extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-addendum/) for Yii.

Comment: I started exploring about the Symfony2, thanks for suggestion.